# Using glide to display multiple images

Tags: java, android, android-glide

For a scanning ticket app, I want to display full screen image.
The app does sequential operation. You scan your QrCode (first image), the device reach server (second image indicating to wait), then I display a third image if the ticket is validate, else I display the last one.
I'm using glide and the image path is indicated in a second activity, I transmit URI to main activity with a sharedPreferences file.

Here is the issue:

```
val settings = getSharedPreferences("PrefFile", 0)
    if (S_mod){//priority on S_mod
        uri_State_init = Uri.parse(settings.getString("mainUri", "none"))
        uri_State_waiting = Uri.parse(settings.getString("waitUri", "none"))
        uri_State_validated = Uri.parse(settings.getString("okUri", "none"))
        uri_State_refused = Uri.parse(settings.getString("errorUri", "none"))
        displayUri( uri_State_init, background)
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.empty)
    }
```

where displayUri is

```
fun displayUri( uri: Uri?, dir:ImageView){//use to display image known by uri, only for full screen
    Glide.with(this)
        .load(uri)
        .error(R.drawable.imagenotfound)  // image in case of error
        .override(1280, 800) // resizing if user doesn't respect the indicated dim
        .centerCrop()//type of resizing
        .into(dir)
}
```

The issue is that only the first image called by displayUri is displayed, the other call show the error image (imagenotfound)

It seem that I've not totally understood the glide extension.

If someone know about this particular issue thanks a lot!!

Comment: maybe the problem is with the uri, are you sure they contain the correct path ?

Comment: and is there any stack trace (expection message) gets printed from glide ? usually if their's a problem with the uri or the photo being loaded Glide takes care of catching the exception and printing its stack trace.

Comment: It display the error image i've set, also i printed the URI in an edittext each time i change the image, it seem good even when the image can't be displayed

Comment: what is really strange is that and the second activity I display an overview of the image selected, and it works with exactly the same code

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
val settings = getSharedPreferences("PrefFile", 0)
if (S_mod){//priority on S_mod
    uri_State_init = Uri.parse(settings.getString("mainUri", "none"))
    uri_State_waiting = Uri.parse(settings.getString("waitUri", "none"))
    uri_State_validated = Uri.parse(settings.getString("okUri", "none"))
    uri_State_refused = Uri.parse(settings.getString("errorUri", "none"))
    displayUri( uri_State_init, background)
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.empty)
}
```

> displayUri( uri_State_init, background)

You are just calling the display Image function with the same uri which means if you didn't passed the uri, then uri will be null and you will definitely get errors. What you can do is to send uri like this ,

```
val settings = getSharedPreferences("PrefFile", 0)

if (S_mod){//priority on S_mod

    uri = Uri.parse(settings.getString("main_uri", "none"))

    displayUri( uri_State_init, background)

    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.empty)

}
```

Just change the value of **main_uri** in Shared Preferences whenever you want to change the state. You can also use **onSharedPreferencesChanged**  Listener.

Comment: I don't see the issue here, if the uri is null the error image will be shown, but in this case uri is selected in "paramactivity" and aren't null, the first call of "displayUri" works and each time I will call this uri it will works also.